# Bounds automatically changes on UIScrollView with content insets

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, uiedgeinsets

I'm using a UIScrollView as my paging scroll view, `pagesScrollView`. Inside that, I put individual UIScrollViews which are used exclusively for zooming. Inside each of those, I have one view which is the page item which should be zoomable. All of that is inside a UINavigationController with a translucent navbar.

My `pagesScrollView` has `contentInset.top = 64` and `bounds.origin.y = -64` (that seems weird to me, but that's what the system is setting automatically for me), and this works just fine. My screen looks great!

However, after I scroll the `pagesScrollView` even a tiny bit, as soon as `scrollViewWillEndDragging` is called, the `pagesScrollView` begins an animated change from `bounds.origin.y = -64` to `bounds.origin.y = 0` which causes my page items to be obscured by the navbar.

On the left is what it looks like when it loads, on the right is what it looks like after I drag just a few pixels and then let go, it slides up under the navbar (because the bounds.origin.y goes to 0).

[image]

The problem is that I don't have any code that is altering the bounds and I don't have any code in the various scroll delegate methods that do anything. I've added a bunch of scroll delegate methods and just added NSLog()s so I can figure out when/where the change is happening, but it's not happening anywhere in my code.

So, I don't know what code I can show you to help you help me.

EDIT: I built a new project from scratch to remove all other variables.. I put a bare UIViewController into a UINavigationController. I put a UIScrollView into my View the entire size of the view. The following code is the entire project.

It turns out the issue (described below) only appears once PAGING IS ENABLED on the UIScrollView! Wtf? :)

Here is a link to download a basic project with only a few lines of code which demonstrates the problem. Just click in the scrollview and you'll see it shift up as the bounds change. http://inadaydevelopment.com/stackoverflow/WeirdScrollViews.zip

How can I have paging enabled on my scrollview without the bounds freaking out during scrolling and shifting everything under the nav bar?

It's possible to set the navbar to opaque and the problem is avoided, but the ideal is to have standard iOS7 behavior so that after the content view is zoomed, THEN the content is allowed to be under the navbar and should show through the translucency normally.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSArray *colors = @[
                        [UIColor blueColor],
                        [UIColor orangeColor],
                        [UIColor magentaColor],
                        ];

    NSArray *zoomerColors = @[
                        [UIColor greenColor],
                        [UIColor yellowColor],
                        [UIColor purpleColor],
                        ];


    self.scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;

    [self.scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scroller.frame.size.width*colors.count, self.scroller.frame.size.height)];

    CGRect subviewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 240);
    for (int index=0; index < colors.count; index++) {
        UIColor *color = [colors objectAtIndex:index];
        UIColor *zoomerColor = [zoomerColors objectAtIndex:index];

        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:subviewFrame];
        subview.backgroundColor = color;

        CGRect zoomerFrame = CGRectMake(index*self.scroller.frame.size.width, 0, self.scroller.frame.size.width, self.scroller.frame.size.height);

        UIScrollView *zoomer = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:zoomerFrame];
        [zoomer addSubview:subview];
        zoomer.backgroundColor = zoomerColor;

        [self.scroller addSubview:zoomer];

    }
}
```

Comment: if you use bounds it x and y point is 0,0 you need to use frame.

Comment: put code of scrollViewWillEndDragging or **put code of individual UIScrollViews**

Comment: @nitinkachhadiya, I'm not changing the bounds at all, and the bounds is starting off at -64... which looks wrong to me, but that's what the system is setting on its own.

Comment: @iPatel, I've added the code you requested, but as I said, it's empty. I didn't even that code method in my class until I added it JUST so I could put an NSLog() in it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an iOS bug. I created the following subclass of `UIScrollView` to get a log of what happens to `y` over time and who was pushing it:

```
@implementation CSScrollView

- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset
{
    NSLog(@"%0.0f %@", contentOffset.y, [NSThread callStackSymbols]);
    NSLog(@"[%@]", self.layer.animationKeys);
    [super setContentOffset:contentOffset];
}

@end
```

(and changed the view class in the storyboard)

When you release your finger, a method called `UIScrollView _smoothScrollDisplayLink:` starts animating the scroll view to its final position. As per the second log, there's no `CAAnimation` involved, the scroll view uses its own display link to do its own transition. That custom code appears to make the mistake of animating from `y = whatever` to `y = 0`, failing to take the content offset into account.

As a proof-of-concept hack I changed the code to:

```
@implementation CSScrollView

- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset
{
    contentOffset.y = -64.0f;
    [super setContentOffset:contentOffset];
}

@end
```

And, unsurprisingly, the problem went away.

You probably don't want to hard code the `-64.0f` but I'd conclude:

- it's an iOS bug;
- work around it by rejecting nonsensical values via a subclass of `UIScrollView` with a suitable custom implementation of `- setContentOffset:`.

A sensible generic means might be to check the `state` of `self.panGestureRecognizer` — that'll allow you to differentiate between scrolls the user is responsible for and other scrolls without relying on any undocumented API or complicated capturing of delegate events. Then if necessary crib the correct `contentOffset.y` from the current value rather than hardcoding it.

Comment: This is great! I couldn't figure out what was wrong, although I did have a suspicion it was a bug in iOS 8. Works perfectly with your solution, thanks

Answer (score 16):

Just switch off Adjust Scroll View Insets

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> My pagesScrollView has contentInset.top = 64 and bounds.origin.y = -64 (that seems weird to me, but that's what the system is setting automatically for me), and this works just fine. My screen looks great!

It because of iOS 7 sets contentInset.top to 64 on all scrollviews.
Just add this line of code into your view controller and all will work as expected:

```
-(UIRectEdge)edgesForExtendedLayout {
return UIRectEdgeNone;
```

}

I checked on your example project.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this answer just avoids the problem instead of truly solving it. When the content view is zoomed and panned, the content should ideally be under the navbar at THAT point and showing through in a standard iOS7 fashion. I can make the navbar opaque and avoid the problem at well, but that's not truly the ideal. This may actually be an iOS bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked you example use below code in viewController.m file

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion].floatValue>=7.0) {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    }
}
```

It's working fine...

Comment: It does prevent the bug from showing up, but that's because it disables the feature that is core to the ui of iOS7. It should ALSO behave properly when the UI is extended.

Answer (score 0):

> It turns out the issue (described below) only appears once PAGING IS ENABLED on the UIScrollView! Wtf? :)

As you said that, If you enable the scroll paging, the UIScrollView will stop at a paging edge after a dragging or any movement, which is promised by the framework. Bounds.origin.y set by zero means that the first page edge matched the scroll view frame edge, cuz you have 64 contentInsets there. So that's not bug, that is what it is. And since your bar is translucent, remember where is your scroll view's frame edge, it's under the bar. In a word, this is not a bug, I think, but a effect of scroll paging.